# My code output always gets 0

Tags: c++

I have a problem statement, which states to count the number of divisors I have between `l` and `r` which gets divided by `k`, however, I always get `0` as my output.

```
int main() {
    int l, r, k, i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = l; i < r; i++) {
        if (i % k = 0) {
            count++; 
        }
        else
            count = count + 0;
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

Comment: The values of `l`, `r`, `k`, and `i` are all unspecified. If you wanted them to start as `0` you should assign them as such, as currently all of their values are unspecified.

Comment: Also, the else-branch seems useless, right?

Comment: i is already initialized in the loop, so I just need to initialize l,r,k with 0 right?

Comment: @anshul If you initialize `l` and `r` with `0`, do you expect your loop to execute at all?

Comment: How can code that doesn't even build produce any output? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11f18125a62ac58e

Comment: Remember: One `=` for assignment, two for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(i % k = 0)
```

This is `UB` since both `i` is initialized with an indeterminate value (`l` being uninitialized) and `k` is uninitialized. Even if you do what @john says, its still `UB` and you can't expect anything or can expect anything as output.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I was doing something really silly.

Answer (score 4):

You need `==` not `=`

`if(i % k == 0){`

`=` is assignment, `==` is the equality test

Comment: It didnt worked either, Still getting the same output that is 0

Comment: @anshul well you probably need some sensible values for `l`, `r`, and `k`. How did you expect your code to work without giving those values? I assumed you'd just left that part of your code out when you posted, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

in if condition change `=` to `==` then set some values to `l, r and k` they are unspecified

**try this!**

```
int main() {
    int l=0, r=10, k=2, i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = l; i < r; i++) {
        if (i % k == 0) {
            count++; 
        }
        else
            count = count + 0;
    }
    cout << count;
}
```